Does power saving mode affect Wakelock? (Android)
After activating the power saving mode, it told me about limiting the background activity, and that some features may work incorrectly.
Can i be certain that if i leave my phone overnight, the app will keep running? Or by limiting background activity, it included wakelock apps?

It is pretty much impossible in modern Android to keep an app running constantly in the background.  I suggest you tell us why you want that, so we can suggest better ways to do it.


Can i be certain that if i leave my phone overnight, the app will keep running?

No.
First, few apps need to run continuously for extended periods of time in the background, such as overnight.
Second, users have stated, very loudly, that they hate apps that unnecessarily run continuously in the background for extended periods of time. As a result, Google and device manufacturers have taken steps to prohibit that behavior.
